# Play Games Gamer ID

Tags: google-play-games

I recently wanted to delete my Google Play Games Gamer ID and start over using the same Gamer ID, which I've done before with no problem. So I proceeded to delete my Gamer ID, however, in the middle of the process, an error occurred. I tried to recreate my Gamer ID immediately after, but says the username is still in use. So now I'm basically locked out of my own Gamer ID because it didn't delete the ID properly. I don't want to create a new Gamer ID, unless it's the Gamer ID that I've always had. How can I regain access to my Gamer ID?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. This is not Google support, you should contact them (https://support.google.com).

Comment: That does not help me.